# Renovating an enclosed porch - insulation and drywall

Tags: drywall, insulation, renovation

I'm renovating a room that used to be a porch and was enclosed in the late 70s. I took down the drywall and this is what I found: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqqrX.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Would appreciate any help to get started on rebuilding this room. Here are my thoughts so far:

1. For the wall insulation -- A plastic vapor barrier was installed in portions of exterior wall where no insulation was installed for some reason. I plan on removing the plastic barrier and installing paper backed insulation instead. I plan to install R-13 paper back insulation everywhere, including the interior wall portions. Most original insulation seems to be in good condition, but some of it is blackened in areas and some has become flattened. Studs are 2x4s.
2. For the ceiling insulation -- I will add R-13 insulation (no paper or foil backed) on top of what is existing.
3. The ceiling frame is 2x3s while the walls are 2x4s. The ceiling originally supported tile and 1/4" drywall since the late 70s but there are two areas along the same 2x3 where the joist was cut for some reason (maybe to make room for recessed lighting). I plan to replace that 2x3 or sister it for better structural integrity and staple the recessed lighting to the joists.
4. So this room used to be a porch that was enclosed and they had built the new roof over the original roof. They even left the original gutter intact. I plan to try and remove the original gutter, although it seems to be held in place by many nails but it seems to make sense to remove it from the attic space.
5. Finally, I plan to use 1/2" ultra light drywall for both walls and ceiling (which should be better than the 1/4" they used in the 70s).

Does this sound right? Anything else I should consider?

Comment: Point 4 seems like a huge waste of effort for no real benefit. What, if any, problem is the heavily nailed in place gutter causing you?

Comment: Are you doing anything to the outside of the exterior wall(s)?  And what type of siding is on it - vinyl, brick, aluminum, stucco...?

Comment: Where are you located?  Is R-13 in the walls going to be enough?  I assume this is going to be conditioned space when you're done.

Comment: But overall, it seems like you have things under control and have a good plan in place.

Comment: New York. I’m considering to leave the foil faced insulation and add more foil faced insulation where there are gaps. Any reason why they may have done foil back in 70s? Or any reason to remove it?

Comment: "Any reason why they may have done foil back in 70s" - not that I know of.  My cynical guess is that foil faced is more expensive then paper faced, and so users trended towards the lower cost solution.  I don't see any reason to remove it.

Comment: For some reason I'm not finding foil faced R-13 insulation at my local hardware store. Could I buy kraft faced insulation and mix and match? (There is already one area of the ceiling where they have kraft faced insulation while everywhere else is foil faced.)

Comment: Sure.  Nothing wrong that I'm aware of mixing types of facing.  They're both there to serve as a vapor barrier/retardant.